# Homotopy theory with condensed sets

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, condensed-mathematics

Is there a canonical way for doing homotopy theory with condensed sets? Is there a definition of homotopy groups? As CW complexes are compactly generated Hausdorff we can consider then as condensed sets, but can we do homotopy theory with general condensed sets?

Comment: This paper might be of interest: https://arxiv.org/abs/2105.07888

Answer (score 9):

Yes. My understanding is that condensed sets are an excellent category to use in order to do homotopy theory.

A couple of results need slightly different proofs and slightly different assumptions in the context of condensed sets (e.g. isomorphism classes of $G$-bundles on $X$ are in bijective correspondence with homotopy classes of maps $X\to BG$), but I expect the adjustments to be rather minor.

That being said, I'm just listing my *expectations* here.
I don't know if anyone took the time to write down any of this.

(Check out
Charles Rezk's comment from Nov 30, 2010
under his answer to my question:
 [Why the "W" in CGWH (compactly generated weakly Hausdorff spaces)?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/47702/why-the-w-in-cgwh-compactly-generated-weakly-hausdorff-spaces/47724#47724))